# What is meaning of "alpha review" in s/w project management?

Tags: project-management

What is the meaning of "Alpha Review" for any software project?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very early version of a software product that may not contain all of the features that are planned for the final version. Typically, software goes through two stages of testing before it is considered finished. The first stage, called alpha testing, is often performed only by users within the organization developing the software. The second stage, called beta testing , generally involves a limited number of external users.

So to answer your question, it is a development status that usually means the first feature complete version of a program or application, that is most likely unstable, but is useful to show what the product will do to, usually, a selected group. Sometimes this stage is referred to as a preview version. Sometimes no more features are added after this release, but bug fixes continue. This release comes after a pre-alpha version and before a beta version.

IMHO, you can easily substitute review with testing.